# flutter android app crashes on geolocation permission request

Tags: android, xml, geolocation, dart, flutter

My flutter android app is crashing after I add permission request of geolocation in android xml file ,if I remove it no crashes happen.Any help???
i am using s7 samsung as a test device with android 8.0

Comment: can you upload the `logCat` data

Comment: I will upload it tomorrow

Comment: Dahm... Tomorrow is long away...

Comment: @serjomacken Can you tell me how you solved this issue?